# IDs showing and not name on front end

Tags: database, jhipster

After generating my entities and relationships, on the front end, when selecting a category that a product belongs to, instead of seeing previously created category i see the categorys ID

jdl used to create the entites are:

entity Product {
    name String,
    description String,
    image ImageBlob
}

```
entity Category {
name String
```

}

```
relationship OneToOne {
Product { category } to Category {Product(name)}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you found the answer. In relations with JDL, when u use this :

```
 Product { Category(name) }
```

The product, in the front end, have one field for select the category, for example   **name**, or other definite in **parenthesis** ().

*Note*: If you don't define parenthesis, this create one field in front end for ID, because this is for default.

Answer (score 0):

relationship should be created like this

```
relationship OneToOne {
    Product { Category(name) } to Category {Product(name)}
}
```